# Laravel 5.3 check if email exists only if password field is filled in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

My application uses the standard validator, and my form makes the user provide an email address. They may continue as a guest, but if they do want to create an account; the only thing they will have to provide is a password and in combination with that email address will create the user account.

However, my issue is I am not sure how to use the validator exists only if the password field has been filled in.

```php
$this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|confirmed|email',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'street_1' => 'required',
    'zip_code' => 'required',
    'phone_1' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required_if:account,1|confirmed',
]);
```

I could do a check and return redirect with an error message, but I'd prefer to go through the validator if I can.

Comment: How about adding an if to check for $request->password and if yes then use the validate method

Comment: I am confused, you only want to validate the password field if __?

Comment: Sorry my explanation wasn't very good. http://imgur.com/yUMjQrY here is my form. They are required to fill in an email address. However, they also have an option to create an account and only thing they need is that email address and a password. I need the validator to check if the email account is in the users table only if the password field has been filled. If not then it treats it as a guest account and doesn't get validated through the users table.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to put your validation rules into an array then perform your desired check. So if the user checked the "account creation" checkbox, add the rules.

```
$rules = [
    'first_name' => 'required',
    'last_name' => 'required',
    'street_1' => 'required',
    'zip_code' => 'required',
    'phone_1' => 'required',
    'password' => 'required_if:account,1|confirmed',
]

if ($request->input('acount') == 1) {
    $rules['email'] = 'required|confirmed|email'
}
```